# Android Unable to pause activity Receiver not registered

Tags: android, exception

What is the cause of this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity { 
com.test/com.test.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
        Receiver not registered: android.widget.VideoView$EventReceiver@98976  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)  at
        android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)  at
        android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)  at
        android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)  at 
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at 
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  at
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)  at 
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  at 
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArg…
```

Comment: We will need more information to help you, such as the source code related to this stack trace.

Comment: Did you find any fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Is your activity connecting to a service? If so, check that you are not unbinding from the service twice.

I had a similar problem where my activity needed to bind and unbind as it was started / paused. Called unbind too many times when pausing and that error was thrown.

Hope this helps